# XML::Twig add space before the enclosing >

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I have :

```
<data id="010" name="Common"  action="text"> 
...
</data>
```

how to use XML::Twig  to add space before ">" i.e something like :

```
<data id="010" name="Common"  action="text" > 

</data>
```

any idea ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: i am trying to generate the same xml that other system generating on different language , it should be exactly the same  (i.e when doing diff there should be no difference ) , thats one of the requirements .

Comment: OK, it's a yucky requirement, as any conforming XML parser will ignore the space and you should be able to generate a diff that ignores changes in space characters as well. However looking at the code for `XML::Twig` the only way to do it would be to override `XML::Twig::end_tag()`

Comment: please tell me that the two spaces between `”Common”` and `action` are just to be ignored also?

Comment: @vanHoesel who was that comment aimed at?

Comment: it’s more something for @jsor , I would get very nervous if those random double spaces are part of the requirement too. I can not imagine ( or maybe I can considering the amount of rubbish XML writers and readers there exists in the wild)  that those double spaces are needed too.

Answer (score 2):

It would not be pretty, but you could change the way XML::Twig outputs start tags.
The method is `start_tag`, in XML::Twig::Elt;

The cleanest way to do this would be to subclass XML::Twig::Elt (as `my_elt` in the code below) and to change the output of the original `start_tag` method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
# elements will be created as "my_elt" instead of XML::Twig::Elt                      
my $t= XML::Twig->new( elt_class => 'my_elt')  
                ->parse( '<data id="010" name="Common"> text </data>')
                ->print;


# create a new class, based on 'XML::Twig::Elt'
package my_elt;
use base 'XML::Twig::Elt';

# my_elt only tweaks start_tag
sub start_tag
  { my $s= shift->SUPER::start_tag(); # get the original start tag
    $s=~ s{(>\s*)$}{ $1}s;            # replace the last '>' by ' >'
    return $s;                        # voilà!
  }
```